# When woken up from sleep, some Chrome windows are blurry

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, google-chrome, display

I have a 2nd monitor attached to my Retina MBP. I was on OS X Mavericks and had this problem, where sometimes the displays would go to sleep and when I wake them, many tabs within Chrome look blurry on my main Retina screen.

When I move the tabs over to the non-retina monitor, it actually fixed it. i.e. the solution is to temporarily move the tab to the non-retina monitor (drop it there) and then bring it back and all of a sudden it looks crispy clear again.

Obviously this is a non-scalable/sustainable strategy.

I assumed that by upgrading to Yosemite that would take care of that, but it didn't. I am still seeing it.

Not all tabs are blurry, and the only ones that seem to be blurry are my Chrome tabs. I haven't tried Safari or anything else yet.

Any ideas for what may be causing this?

Here is a screenshot of a Chrome tab looking blurry.

[image: blurry example]

Comment: What is that screen shot of?

Comment: A screenshot of Chrome looking fuzzy/blurry.

Comment: have the same exact issue with my MBPr, both on OSX 10.9 and now 10.10 as well. Its worth noting that on [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) I do not have this issue, so hopefully Chrome stable will be updated with a fix soon!

Comment: Same problem here! OSX 10.9.5 and Chrome 38. I also seem to have it after opening up my macbook from sleep mode.

Comment: Also experiencing this problem. Moving or resizing the window temporarily fixes this issue. Mac OS X 10.10, Chrome 38.0.2125.104.

Comment: It seems it may have been fixed in the latest update of Chrome, because I no longer have this issue. Can others confirm? Edit: Scratch that...it isn't fully fixed. Less tabs are having the issue, but ironically Gmail and a bunch of others still do.

Comment: Resizing the window clears up the blurry screen but doesn't prevent it.

Comment: Seems to me like it doesn't happen on every sleep. I still have to verify, but it looks like it happens when I sleep it with external monitor connected and wake up without or vice-versa.

Comment: Also issue in Chromium regarding that: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428026

Comment: @vartec yeah I think you are right on that, I've experienced the same. I'd bet it has to with how Chrome is determining whether or not it should render the the pages in regards to pixel density. When the MBPr is connected to a non-HIDPI display, Chrome must be thinking that it should display in non-retina mode when the displays are turned on.

Comment: I get this too. It's only some tabs though. It didn't happen on my old MBPR, but it happens on my new one. I have the Intel Iris 1536 graphics card.

Comment: @michael Check if you have any available updates for Chrome. After I updated to the most recent version (39.0.2171.71) the issue no longer occurs.

Comment: it is not a chrome specific issue. i have experienced this with top top bar (time, battery, etc.) and then after a few minutes it went back to normal. I have the latest update for yosemite. the issue still occurs. with chrome and e.g. the top bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but It looks like the latest stable release (39.0.2171.71, released 11/25), may have fixed this.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm this? I am not 100% certain either. It seems so, but only time will tell for me.

Comment: I believe this is fixed for me too.

Comment: I'm on 43.0.2357.132 (64-bit) and still experience this from time to time...

Answer (score 0):

Is the external monitor always connected to your machine?

I'm not sure this will work or if this is a viable solution, but try to set the external monitor as your primary display and report back.

Comment: It is just a Chrome specific problem. So I doubt this will fix it permanently.